# angularjs creating dynamic form elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have my html elements like this:

```
<body ng-controller="addController">
<div class="col-sm-10">

    <label class="control-label">tableName:</label> 
    <fieldset ng-repeat="tableName in tableNames">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tableName.tableName" /><br />
    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewTable()">Add tablename</button>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="add()" />    
</div>
<div>
   <pre>{{tableNames|json}}</pre> 
</div>
</body>
```

This code generates a text box every time button is clicked.

js:

```
function addController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.tableNames = [];
        $scope.addNewTable = function (tableName) {
            $scope.tableNames.push({});

        }
}
```

When i display tableNames it gives me:

```
[{"tableName":"textboxvalue"},{"tableName":"textboxvalue"}];
```

But what i intend is getting output of:

```
[{"tableName1":"textboxvalue","tableName2":"textboxvalue","tableName3":"textboxvalue"}];
```

What should I have to change in design in order to get desired output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting `ng-model="tableName['tableName' + ($index + 1)]"` for input element

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing objects to the array each time but what you want is to add key value pair in the object in the array.
try this

```
 $scope.tableNames = [{}];
    $scope.addNewTable = function (tableName) {
        $scope.tableNames[0].tableName = "textboxvalue" ;

    }
```